# Publish feeds using PubSubHubbub

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, feed

Updating the SO feeds to use [PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) is easy, would accelerate the propagation of updates and will save bandwith for the publisher and subscribers

How?

One of the steps are:

In RSS add right after the opening "channel" tag:

```
<atom:link rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/>
```

In Atom inside the "feed" tag:

```
<link rel="hub" href="http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com"/>
```

Comment: If I get this correctly, you are suggesting to push the stuff instead of pulling it. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, I am suggesting to have the push option, without breaking any existing functionality

Comment: Then I have to upvote you.

Comment: Upvoting this as well. PubSubHubbub on SO would be really nice.

Comment: How does this affect existing RSS feeds that users already have? What about subscribing to new ones? Would the usage be identical to what we already have?

Answer (score 12):

This would be wonderful! I actually offered Jeff (who pointed me to the topic) and Joel a few weeks ago to host a hub for them.

The Appspot hub is great, but it was built as a "demo" initially, even though it is now used by most of Google's properties.

However, I think the [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) hosted hubs offer a few other cool features, like *export of the data* (that that appspot hub doesn't have), *analytics*, and a few other neat features that we're announcing soon. We **already host hubs** for the folks at Tumblr, Posterous, Gawker Media, HuffPost and several other publishers (big or small). I'd love to count the SO feeds as well!

Jader, there are actually 2 steps to making feeds realtime.

- The first one (**discovery**) is roughly what you describe. (It's important for RSS feeds to add a link, with `rel="self"`).
- The 2nd step is to **ping** the hub whenever a feed is updated. The hub will then fetch the feed, make diffs (to see the old vs. new entries), and notify subscribers (obviously!).

All in all, no matter how you decide to do it (Superfeedr or Google), I think this is a great step for the community and that will allow people to build interesting clients that can consumer the SO data out of SO. (who said IM bot?)

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE** It's now been over a year publishing data to pubsubhubbub and we haven't really seen much use at this point and are considering closing this service.  Stats show that we are being pinged by the hub but we have no visibility as far as who is using the feeds provided by the hub.

How many of you are actually using this service and would hate to see it go?

---

We now support pubsubhubbub on single question feeds via http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com on stackoverflow.com and meta.stackoverflow.com only at the moment.  We will be working to make other feeds available in the future (tags, tag combinations, etc).

I threw together a really quick app to demo  the real-time nature of pubsubhubbub here:

http://pubsubhubsample.apphb.com/

Just paste the question feed url located at the bottom of every question and click subscribe - wait for a confirmation and then answer a question.  All future answers posted will automatically be shown as they come in.

Single tag feeds are now supported

Check:  https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/java

Comment: uh... I don't think the latest SO question has been asked two hours ago.

Comment: @badp I am not sure what you're referring to here

Comment: er... When I clicked the link yesterday there was a list of Java question, the latest being 2 hours old. Now I see some kind of feed reader interface instead. I'm confused; then again I really didn't understand what the hell PubSubHubBub means for subscribers, without understand it's really a feature of Google Reader and possibly other feed readers, so subscribers really don't have anything to do to get the benefits.

Comment: HUGE! Thanks a lot Geoff! Feel free to check out http://superfeedr.com if you ever want to have your very own hub + analytics + export :)

Comment: @GeoffDalgas A separate question might get more visibility.

Comment: Possibly - we'll see what this turns up first.

Answer (score 0):

I would really love to see Pubsubhubbub-Support (every time a have to type this I think I got it wrong o_O ) on SO, SV and SU.